# Is it possible to always have the latest version of the deb package of vs code installed?

Tags: dpkg, deb, visual-studio-code

I want to install the latest version of vs code in Pop OS. The apt repository doesn't offer the latest version and I don't prefer flatpaks/snaps so installing the deb package of vs-code from the official site is apparently the only option left now.

My question is this - If I proceed with the installation of the latest version of vs code deb package now and after a few weeks let's suppose another version of vs-code comes out, would I have to download and install that deb package again and delete the older one so I can always use the latest version? Or is there a simpler way to always have the latest version installed without having to manually repeat the delete-download-install process all over again every time an upgrade is out on the official site?

Answer (score 0):

If you download [the upstream `.deb` package](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and install it, it configures APT to track Microsoft’s repository; you’ll then get upgrades as they are released, by the usual `apt update` mechanisms or systems built on top of that (*e.g.* PackageKit or GNOME Software).